# php socket programming with auth

Tags: php, sockets, authentication, tcp

i want to read file from remote server with Socket programing but server protected with http_auth

and i could not get socket working even with providing tcp://username:passwrod@hostname.com

i got this error

```
 php_network_getaddresses: getaddrinfo failed: No such host is known. (0)
```

here is my code

```
$fp = stream_socket_client(" tcp://username:passwrod@hostname.com:80", $errno, $errstr, 30);
if (!$fp) {
    echo "$errstr ($errno)<br />\n";
} else {
    fwrite($fp, "GET / HTTP/1.0\r\nHost: hostname.com\r\nAccept: */*\r\n\r\n");
    while (!feof($fp)) {
        echo fgets($fp, 1024);
    }
    fclose($fp);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Well, for one, you have a typo in the TCP string:

```
" tcp://username:passwrod@hostname.com:80"
```

should be

```
"tcp://username:password@hostname.com:80"
```

By itself, the extra space at the start of your URI will cause your`stream_socket_client` call to fail, and I imagine it's responsible for the `getaddrinfo` error as the host cannot be resolved if the URI string is invalid. Furthermore, even once the DNS issue is resolved, the authentication will fail because `password` is misspelled as `passwrod`.

Assuming it still doesn't work after that, you should have a look at your DNS settings. `getaddrinfo failed: No such host is known` means that your server cannot figure out where `hostname.com` is located... so before you start worrying about authentication or ports, just make sure that

- `hostname.com` is a valid URL
- the DNS service is configured correctly on your server (try to run a few simple ones that should definitely work, like `$fp = stream_socket_client("tcp://yahoo.com:80", $errno, $errstr, 30); var_dump($fp);` - if that call doesn't return a resource then your DNS service is not functioning correctly... or you could just try pinging from the server to see if you can reach www.yahoo.com.
- Check your server's proxy settings

Comment: dose not make any different and i tested both and result are same ;)

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
<?php
if(!($fp = fsockopen("hostname", 80)))
{
    throw new Exception("Couldn't open socket!\n");
}
fputs($fp, "GET / HTTP/1.0\r\n");
fputs($fp, "Host: hostname\r\n");

fputs($fp, "Authorization: Basic " .
    base64_encode("username:password") .
    "\r\n");

fputs($fp, "\r\n");

fpassthru($fp);
?>
```

Comment: i get this error with that code  WWW-Authenticate: Basic realm="MultiShare Login"  401

Comment: The code works good - the auth failed. Have you replaced username:password with the right credentials? Try using the same within the browser.

Also try adding the Host header.